# iptables port forward prerouting - how to exclude local LAN?

Tags: iptables

I use several PREROUTING rules in Jessie Debian to do port forward from WAN to LAN ip with following rule

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 8088 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.6:8088

ETH0 is public static IP
ETH0:0 is Local lan ip 192.168.1.2
```

These are NAT related IPTABLES

```
iptables -t nat -L -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  -- !192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8088 to:192.168.1.6:8088
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8091 to:192.168.1.7:80
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8092 to:192.168.1.1:80
DNAT       tcp  -- !192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10554 to:192.168.2.10:554
DNAT       udp  -- !192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:10554 to:192.168.2.10:554
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10080 to:192.168.2.1:8081
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10443 to:192.168.2.4:10443
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10052 to:192.168.2.1:8080
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:34567 to:192.168.2.10:34567
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10050 to:192.168.2.1:10050

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
SNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.10         tcp dpt:554 to:192.168.1.2
SNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.10         udp dpt:554 to:192.168.1.2
SNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.1          tcp dpt:8081 to:192.168.1.2
SNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.4          tcp dpt:10443 to:192.168.1.2
SNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.1          tcp dpt:8080 to:192.168.1.2
SNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.10         tcp dpt:34567 to:192.168.1.2
SNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.1          tcp dpt:10050 to:192.168.1.2
```

However this rule is applied also when accessing that port from LAN. As result I can enter any IP and port 8088 to browser URL and it will always reach destination. for example I can enter http://1.1.1.1:8088 and it will work. this is not desired behaviour.

I'd like to exclude LAN from PREROUTING.

I tried ! -s 192.168.0.0/24 but in prerouting "!" for source parameter does not work

I tried also another approach to use destination parameter "-d mydoman.com" in the rule, but this only works if I remove mydoman.com line from /etc/hosts because mydoman.com links to server local network IP. I'd like to keep that record too.

is there better way to avoid prerouting rule for local network?

Comment: What do you mean by 'for source parameter does not work'? You can use ! for source address in the PREROUTING chain without any problem.

Comment: I mean that agent with LAN ip 192.168.1.8 still can access service by entering https://any.ip.addres:8088 on port 8088 even if this rule is applied `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING ! -s 192.168.0.0/24 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8088 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.6:8088`

Comment: Shouldn't work. Could you add list of rules from nat table to the question

Comment: yes, I also think it Shouldn't work. added iptables list NAT relevant portion

Comment: Is 192.168.1.2 default gateway for 192.168.0.0/24 subnet? Have you checked counter for the rule when clients get access to the 192.168.1.6:8088. Does the counter growing?

Comment: Am I correct in saying that you are using the same physical interface for both WAN and LAN, which is confirmed by your use of eth0 and eth0:0 ? This is very odd way to be doing things. These are basically the same interface. eth0:0 is the convention for using IP aliases on the same physical interface. A completely separate interface is required, eg. eth1, or a vlan interface, like eth0.1, for this to work as expected.

Comment: replacing eth0:0 with vlan eth0.1 would be good thing, but that is not that easy, I'd need to bring switch supporting vlan tagging in interfaces. if I understand that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to exclude `192.168.1.8` from the DNAT rule, you shall use `192.168.0.0/23` or `192.168.1.0/24` as the `! -s` parameter. The network range `192.168.0.0/24` finishes at `192.168.0.255`.

```
$ ipcalc 192.168.0.0/24
Address:   192.168.0.0          11000000.10101000.00000000. 00000000
Netmask:   255.255.255.0 = 24   11111111.11111111.11111111. 00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.255            00000000.00000000.00000000. 11111111
=>
Network:   192.168.0.0/24       11000000.10101000.00000000. 00000000
HostMin:   192.168.0.1          11000000.10101000.00000000. 00000001
HostMax:   192.168.0.254        11000000.10101000.00000000. 11111110
Broadcast: 192.168.0.255        11000000.10101000.00000000. 11111111
Hosts/Net: 254
```

---

You may restrict the DNAT rule by interfaces instead of using addresses. For example:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING '!' -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8088 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.6:8088
```

Or:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ${your_wan_interface} -p tcp --dport 8088 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.6:8088
```

Using the RETURN target is also a possible choice:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8088 -j RETURN
```

Comment: Many thanks Anderson, how I could completely forget count proper mask... in fact I need to exclude `192.168.1-3.x` - and indeed using mask /22 will fit and work also for PREROUTING. What confused me was that some people in forums says that "! -s" is not supported. indeed wrong information. I will be probably using mask approach however will also review  "restrict the DNAT rule by interfaces" and RETURN options later

Comment: The [IPTABLES manpage](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html) doesn't mention any restriction on using the exclamation mark in source specification nor in PREROUTING chain, so it's supposed to work.