# Allow Specific IP to bypass NAT command in LINUX

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I am using these commands to Redirect Incoming to another Port

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 4367 -j REDIRECT --to-port 11222
```

Using the Above command I Redirect all Incoming Traffic to port 11222.

I want to Redirect All Incoming traffic except traffic coming from this ip 123.55.1.3.
That Traffic Should directly go to port 4367
Actually there are two similar applications which run on udp port 4367 & udp 11222.
Only traffic with source 123.55.1.3 should go to 4367.
Can anyone help me how can it be done?

I saw this similar post [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/759130/iptables-port-forward-prerouting-how-to-exclude-local-lan) But I could not understand which rule to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the bypass rule above the `REDIRECT` rule.

The next command insert the bypass rule at the top of `nat/PREROUTING` chain:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING --src 123.55.1.3 -p udp --dport 4367 -j ACCEPT
```

Note, usage of iptables to change the firewall rule set isn't safe - you can lost the control. Better use the iptables-apply tool to get the rollback feature.